Is there an opposite of std::format?
Standard format can do the following, where tm is an std::tm:
const auto time = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(std::mktime(&tm));
const std::string s = std::format("{:%d %b %Y}", time);
//Example s: 20 March 1990

Is there a function where I can pass in 20 March 1990 and get a time_point?
Something like this:
const std::string data = "20 March 1990";
const auto time = std::make_time_point("{:%d %b %Y}", data);

A solution where I can do the following will also work:
int a = 0;
std::string b = 0;
int c = 0;
const std::string data = "20 March 1990";
std::reverse_format("{} {} {}", data, &a, &b, &c);
//Output: a = 20, b = March, c = 1990

I would like to avoid stringstreams in the solution.
Edit in response to closing: The accepted answer in the provided "duplicate" uses stringstream, which I specifically asked not to use. Additionally, the other option is both non-standard and UNIX only.
I need to avoid stringstreams because I am parsing an enormous amount of data and I have found stringstreams to be reducing performance significantly. I currently have a horrible solution with stringview and lots of substrs which I am trying to replace with a more elegant one.

There's std::chrono::parse

@IgorTandetnik I don't think there is any way to use that without stringstreams

There's scnlib, but I've never tried it myself.

To avoid stringstreams, maybe you'd want to use Spirit X3 and write your own grammar using the Spirit parsing framework.
